# Duda con módulo "queue" utilizado en multi-hilos en python

Tags: python, hilos, queue

Estoy aprendiendo Python y en este punto me surgieron dudas, agradecería si alguien puede darme una orientación. Aquí parte del código:

```
counter = 0
job_queue = queue.Queue()
counter_queue = queue.Queue()


def increment_manager():
    global counter
    while True:
        print(threading.current_thread().getName())
        increment = counter_queue.get()  # this waits until an item is available and locks the queue
        time.sleep(random.random())
        old_counter = counter
        time.sleep(random.random())
        counter = old_counter + increment
        time.sleep(random.random())
        job_queue.put((f'New counter value {counter}', '------------'))
        time.sleep(random.random())
        counter_queue.task_done()  # this unlocks the queue


# printer_manager and increment_manager run continuously because of the `daemon` flag.
Thread(target=increment_manager, name='Mythread', daemon=True).start()
```

Mi duda es:

Si utilizo el módulo **queue** para evitar que distintos **threads** modifiquen la variable **count** al mismo tiempo produciendo resultados no deseados (aquí deseo obtener una salida que muestre un contador en forma secuencial del 1 al 10) ¿qué sentido tendría en este caso cuando tengo un único hilo que se ocupa de ejecutar la función 'increment manager'?

Muchas gracias por leer y por la ayuda que puedan brindarme.

Comment: La cola no solo puede ser útil para evitar condiciones de carrrera, también sirve para comunicar al resto de hilos o al principal cuando un hilo a terminado de procesar una entrada o la cola completa por ejemplo. Lo digo porque usas task_done, esto solo tiene sentido si usas counter_queue.join() en el hilo principal o en el consumidor (printer), código que no muestras. Obviamente si tienes un solo productor el problema de las condiciones de carrera es menor o puede no darse, dependiendo de como se implemente el consumidor y que haga exactamente.

Comment: Muchas gracias Jorge por tu respuesta, tenia algo abandonado las practicas. Recien ahora puedo retomar. Saludos.

Comment: Puedo consultarte algo? es sobre el mismo codigo. En vez de usar un hilo unico uso una cantidad n de hilos y el codigo no funciona como quisiera. Quiero que cada hilo se ocupe de recuperar un valor de un queue ( que almacena diez '1') y de ese modo vaya incrementando en una unidad  la variable global (counter). Porque cuando un hilo ejecuta la funcion increment manager() no impide que otros la accedan produciendose de este modo un acceso concurrente a dicha variable y por ende resultados y valores no deseados. Agradeceria si pudieras orientarme.